# Animate Left Side of Top Triangle Aligned to the Left side of Menu Element Selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website for my own and I don't know how to solve this animation part.

I have a regular Menu and on the top right corner I have a triangle, a white triangle with position absolute and 0 to the right. The point of the triangle is facing to the left side.

I want to animate it (increase size of the left side) and reach the left side of the selected element of the menu.

You can see what I'm talking about on the next image

[![Example][1]][1]

Also, I want to animate it on hover not click, if you stop hovering an element I would like it to go back to initial position. I have the html/css structure but not sure how to animate it to reach exactly the left corner of the menu element.

HTML

```
<div id="sectionHeader">

    <div id="sectionHeaderTriangle"></div>

    <div id="sectionHeaderCentralizer">

        <img id="sectionHeaderLogo" src="images/logo.svg"/>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">How it Works?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="sectionHeaderContentBox">
            <div class="text1">PAGE TEST</div>
            <div class="text2">Some Temporal Text goes here...</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}

/*  Section Header  */

#sectionHeader {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #29251f;
}

#sectionHeaderCentralizer {
position: relative;
width: 1200px;
height: 450px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
padding: 10px;
background-color: ;
}

#sectionHeaderLogo {
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: 30px;
}

#sectionHeaderContentBox {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
height: auto;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
background-color: ;
}

#sectionHeaderTriangle {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 2px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
border-right: 40px solid white;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 20px;
}

/*primero en el móvil (mobile first)*/

nav {
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
top: 45px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
width: auto;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

nav li a {
color: white;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: .5em 1em;
}

nav li a:hover {
color: #13baff;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.text1 {
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-size: 65px;
color: #fff;
}

.text2 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
width: 650px;
}

/* @media-query */

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
nav ul {
display: flex;
}

nav li{
/*la caja puede crecer para ocupar todo el espacio disponible */
flex-grow:1; 
text-align:center;
}
}
```

Can someone guide me? :) thanks!

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOyQa.png
```

Comment: add the selector hover in css

Comment: Hello @Fatima Zohra thanks! well that's not the problem. I can make a hover effect to animate the left side of the triangle, and simply increase the size; But I need it to reach the left corner of the element of the menu hovered, no matter the size of the screen, like the image attached.

I mean I could do this:

nav li.li_1:hover > #sectionHeaderTriangle {

border-right: 450px solid white;

}

But as you can see won't be accurate :( I need it to reach the left corner of the element hovered on the menu always, if the screen is smaller it should also reach the same corner of it